# Setting integer default value - SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I am trying to set a integer to a default value in a stored procedure as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SomeSProc
    @Year int = datepart(year, getdate()) 
AS
BEGIN
...
```

I keep getting this error:

> Incorrect syntax near '('.

but cannot see anything wrong.

Comment: Defaults in stored procedure parameters can only be **constants** - not expressions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a constant expression, NULL is a common choice;

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SomeSProc
    @Year int = null
AS
BEGIN

if (@Year is null)
    set @year = datepart(year, getdate())
```